# Copy folder data to other folder in network

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

De

I have to copy folders and files from one network folder to other. There are some files which cannot be copied since it is named with special characters.
There are so many folders and sub-folders with 3 GB of data. To avoid this problem, I want to write a C# program which can copy all folders, sub-folders and files
with a log file(notepad). Log file which should note the non-copying file details and its path so that easy to trace them further. Can anybody please help me quickly
by providing a c# program or at-least a reference. A console or Win-form application, I am using Visual studio 2010 and Windows 7

copying like below

Copy form :- https://ap.sharepoint.a5-group.com/cm/Shared Documents/IRD/EA

To :- https://cr.sp.a5-group.com/sites/cm/Shared Documents/IRD/EA

Comment: Have you attempted any code? It seems that you would want to do a recursive file copy from your source to your destination.

Answer (score 2):

here, try this:

Edit: my answer works for local Network Directories, I didn't mention, that you want to copy directiories from HTTPS, for that you have to use WebClient with Credentials

```
class DirectoryCopyExample
    {
        string pathFrom = "C:\\someFolder";
        string pathTo = "D:\\otherFolder";
        string LogText = string.Empty;
        static void Main()
        {
            // Copy from the current directory, include subdirectories.
            DirectoryCopy(pathFrom, pathTo, true);
        }

        private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
        {
            // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                    "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                    + sourceDirName);
            }

            // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it. 
            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }

            // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
                    file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    //Write Files to Log whicht couldn't be copy
                    LogText += DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + file.FullName;
                }
            }

            // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location. 
            if (copySubDirs)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                    DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

at the end you have to save the variable LogTex to the file, or whatever you need

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx